# Zend Framework how to echo value of SUM query

Tags: zend-framework, sum, zend-db

I created a query for the zend framework, in which I try to retrieve the sum of a column, in this case the column named 'time'. This is the query I use:

```
$this->timequery = $this->db_tasks->fetchAll($this->db_tasks->select()->from('tasks', 'SUM(time)')->where('projectnumber =' . $this->value_project));


$this->view->sumtime = $this->timequery;
```

Echoing the query tells me this is right. But I can't echo the result properly. Currently I'm using:

```
echo $this->sumtime['SUM(time)'];
```

Returning the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend_Db_Table_Row could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\BManagement\application\views\scripts\tasks\index.phtml  on line 46
```

Line 46 being the line with the echo in my view.

I've been searching now for two days on how to figure this out, or achieve the same result in a different way. Tried to serialize the value, but that didn't work either.

Is there somebody who knows how to achieve the total sum of a database column?

Any help is greatly appriciated!

note: Pretty new to zend framework...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Zend_Db has some nice utility methods like fetchAll (which you're using) to fetch different types of data:

- fetchAll - for a set of rows
- fetchRow - for a single row
- fetchOne - for a single cell

Most simply:

```
$sum = $db->fetchOne('SELECT SUM(time) FROM tasks WHERE project_number = ?', $this->value_project);
```

You can use Zend_Db_Select with these methods too, like in your question:

```
//note that the SUM(time) part is passed as a Zend_Db expression, as it is not a column
$select = $this->db_tasks->select()
                         ->from('tasks', new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(time)'))
                         ->where('projectnumber =' . $this->value_project);

$this->timequery = $this->db_tasks->fetchOne($select);
```

This works because the Zend_Db_Select object implements a toString method, to produce SQL.

Comment: Hi David,

First of all thanks! But I'm still getting an error bacK:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Application_Model_DbTable_Tasks::fetchOne()

Does this means it cannot find fetchOne in the class?

Changing it to fetchRow or fetchAll again gives the error that it cannot convert to a string.

Almost there!

Comment: If figured it out:

The last sentence had to be: 
$this->view->timequery = $this->db_tasks->getAdapter()->fetchOne($select);

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah - I had assumed that $this->db_tasks was a database adapter, not a Zend_Db_Table. You have the right solution with getAdapter

Answer (score 1):

```
$timequery= $timequeriestb->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
                          ->columns('SUM(time) AS Totaltime')
                          ->where('projectnumber ='. $this->value_project));
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you want is probably:

```
SELECT SUM(time) AS time_sum FROM tasks ...
```

Not sure how to do this in Zend. Then:

```
echo $this->sumtime['time_sum'];
```

Comment: Already tried that as well, but I still get the same error back. I'm guessing the query is good but I'm not echoing the result back in a proper way...